# Will this preg_match prevent XSS successfully?

Tags: php, xss, preg-match

I read that even if you strip `<script>` you are still vulnerable to XSS.

Something interesting I found as an answer is this `<scrip<script></script>t>alert(1337)</script>`

How do you evaluate this preg match?

```
echo preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $var);
```

Additionally, is there any other tags I should be aware for XSS attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strip_tags` is sufficient to get rid of XSS issues. But using a single regex is not, as you need to cleanse and whitelist ***all*** HTML attributes and tags. Browsers are extremely forgiving and allow even malformed HTML that's not standards-compliant (also IE bugs). That's why it is pretty much unfeasible to use a regex for that. (Despite the silly SO meme it *is* possible to match HTML with a contemporary regex language, just way too much effort.)

All the regex solutions you will find are blacklists, which are not considered a reliable solution. They will miss half of the possible exploits http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Comment: Very good comment. Xss can occur without injecting a single tag. See the OWASP xss prevention cheat sheet

Comment: Will strip_tags($text,'<b>') prevent XSS?

Comment: @Nikolai: Yes. That would leave the `<b>` tag over, including all possible attributes. It only works if you strip all tags.

Comment: @mario: i am confused.. Some people say that striptags are not so secure. My purpose is to allow only b,i,u,li.

Comment: @Giorkouros: Well, it's optimum to strip everything with the `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($html))` combination. But using `strip_tags` with exceptions is a no-no.

Comment: But then I will not be able to echo html

Comment: @Giorkouros: Yes, neither of the simple approaches is sufficient for that.

Comment: "strip_tags is sufficient to get rid of XSS issues" is incorrect. It will not prevent XSS for all output contexts. For further information please see - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not sufficient to filter dangerous HTML. You *must* properly parse the HTML, and drop malformed tags as well as non-whitelisted tags. Use an existing library such as [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/); it is *far* too easy to get this wrong.

Comment: Security is _not_ an option. If it kills performance, find a different library, or cache the result. Replacing it with a regex might be faster, but it will kill your _entire site_ as soon as someone with malicious intent realizes what's going on.

Answer (score -2):

You could try eliminating script tags in a while loop, until there is no more script tags to be found:

```
while (preg_match("'[<]script.*?/script[>]'is",$data))
{
    $data = preg_replace("'[<]script.*?/script[>]'is","",$data);
}
```

You should check onevent element properties also, like: onclick, onfocus, etc. They can also contain unwanted XSS.

Comment: What about CSS? Some browsers allow JS injection in CSS. Some allow the script tag to be broken up on multiple lines, or otherwise with junk between `scr` and `ipt`. There are javascript: urls. _The solution is not to enumerate all the possible ways to inject JS._ You _must_ whitelist only what you will accept. Do not attempt to enumerate what you _will not_ accept, because that list is VERY long and always growing.